# link 2019 Error For Simple Class C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I can't seem to fix this LNK2019 Error that I keep getting on visual studio 2013.

I've been looking on stack exchange for a while, but I think my code is fine.
The error is a result of creating a ParkingMeter variable. I'm not sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

ParkingMeter.h:

```
#ifndef PARKINGMETER
#define PARKINGMETER
using namespace std;

class ParkingMeter{
private:
    int minPurchased;
public:
    ParkingMeter(int);
    ParkingMeter();
    int getMinutes();
};
#endif
```

ParkingMeter.cpp:

```
using namespace std;
#include "ParkingMeter.h"
ParkingMeter::ParkingMeter(int minutes)
{
minPurchased = minutes;
}
ParkingMeter::ParkingMeter(){
minPurchased = 0;
}
int ParkingMeter::getMinutes(){ return minPurchased; }
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ParkingMeter.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ParkingMeter meter(2);
}
```

Full error message:

> Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ParkingMeter::ParkingMeter(int)" (??0ParkingMeter@@QAE@H@Z) referenced in function _main C:\Users\Max\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project3\Project3\test.obj

Comment: Probably a silly question but: are all these files in a single project?  Are you building the project, and not just a single file?

Comment: Show the **FULL** error. It contains important information. Looks like your project is set up incorrectly.

Comment: All of these files are in a single project. I'm not building a single file. I don't even know how to do that with Visual Studio. I'm building the entire project.

Comment: Full error message:Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ParkingMeter::ParkingMeter(int)" (??0ParkingMeter@@QAE@H@Z) referenced in function _main C:\Users\Max\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project3\Project3\test.obj

Comment: The code that is posted here builds fine. There must be some difference between this code and your actual code.

Comment: Try to rebuild the solution. That helps in some weird cases.

Comment: I'm not familiar with visual Studio. The project was created with default settings.  Any idea what I need to change?

Comment: This code here should not be changed, because it is correct, and it builds in my Visual Studio. To "rebuild the solution" go to menu Build and select Rebuild solution. Also, maybe there's some difference in your actual code, so replace your actual code with the code from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with this code.

I have removed below code from your `ParkingMeter.h` and `ParkingMeter.cpp`. (keep in `test.cpp` file)

```
using namespace std;
```

Edit: It seems you have not added `ParkingMeter.cpp` in your project. Please right click on your `project - > Add -> existing Item -> and provide cpp file`. You are good to go!

Comment: I was thinking it wasn't necessary in all three files. I removed it from the header, but it didn't have an effect on the error.

Comment: I posted it in the comments above. Thanks!

Comment: @user2284725 Are you able to fix issue?

Comment: For some reason I couldn't fix the issue in the project I had already created, but I created a new project and made three new files with the exact same code, and it works now. I'm not sure what I did to mess up the other project. Thanks for the help!